# how can i customize google signup template in django

Tags: django, google-cloud-platform, django-templates

before i finish signup this template apper and i want to customize it
urls.py

```
path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
path('users/', include('users.urls', namespace='users')),
```

setting.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic',
    'grappelli',
    'captcha',
    'users',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',]
SOCIALACCOUNT_LOGIN_ON_GET=True
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'google': {
        'SCOPE': [
            'profile',
            'email',
        ],
        'AUTH_PARAMS':{'access_type':'online'}
    }
}
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home:home'
LOGIN_URL = 'users:login'



AUTHENTICATION_BACKEND=(
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
)
```

i make templates>account>sinup.html but it did not work